# How to hide Title bar in WPF Ribbon Window (Aero enabled) without hidden control box?

Tags: wpf, ribbon-control, window-chrome

I currently use WPF Ribbon Window and enable Aero in current window like the following photo. I like to hide title that is "Pattern Tester" because there is not enough of space to show it. But I still **need original windows control box** and current title (even it will be hidden) that will be shown in task manager and other ralated program like task switcher and taskbar.

[image: WPF Ribbon Window]

Answer (score 5):

I accidentally found the answer for this question when I read & download source code in thread about [WPF Title Bar Text Hardly Readable in RibbonWindow](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/95d513a0-df83-4afc-836b-0e885a9ed929). The easiest way to solve this problem is just hidden Ribbon Title Panel control via application resource dictionary.

```
 <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:ribbon="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;assembly=RibbonControlsLibrary"
            xmlns:ribbonPre="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon.Primitives;assembly=RibbonControlsLibrary">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ribbonPre:RibbonTitlePanel}">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
    </Style>
 </ResourceDictionary>
```

[image]

However, the Ribbon Contextual Tab is also hidden. For fixing this bug, I should set the content of Content Presenter of Ribbon Title Panel to empty string when current window is loaded.

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var titlePanel = Ribbon.Template.FindName("PART_TitleHost", Ribbon) as ContentPresenter;
    if (titlePanel != null)
    {
        titlePanel.Content = "";
    }
}
```

[image]

The remaining question, I don't know why I cannot the following style instead of hardcode in window onload event.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ribbonPre:RibbonTitlePanel}">
    <Setter Property="ContentPresenter.Content" Value=""/>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 3):

In the Load event of the window, add the next line:

((System.Windows.UIElement)((System.Windows.FrameworkElement)(this.RibbonMain.Template.FindName("PART_TitleHost", this.RibbonMain) as ContentPresenter).Parent).Parent).Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

Comment: I'm using the ribbon on a UserControl and I needed to get rid of the ribbons title area also.  Tried the xaml above but it couldn't find the RibbonTitlePanel in ribbonPre.  So I scrapped that and tried this.  One single line of code in the UserControl Loaded event.  Works like a charm!  Thanks!