# Cannot hide WPF Ribbon title bar

Tags: wpf, ribbon

I've tried to set a style as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6825331/361899) answer but the title bar remains visible.

[image]

Any ideas ?

Environment : WPF 4.5 application / Visual Studio 2012 / Windows 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content needs to be hosted inside a `RibbonWindow` instead.

Comment: If I use the RibbonWindow, then indeed the problem is fixed but suddently it gets the Win2000 look. I'm running Win8x64.

Comment: Sorry but how can you get the Win2K look in Win 8 ? You should ask a question, post a screenshot and some code so people can help you better.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in code behind on the Loaded event.
Loaded="Ribbon_OnLoaded"

```
private void Ribbon_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int childControlCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount((System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon.Ribbon)sender);

        if (childControlCount != 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0;
                i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount((System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon.Ribbon)sender);
                i++)
            {
                DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild((System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon.Ribbon)sender, i);

                if (child is Grid)
                {
                    ((Grid)child).RowDefinitions[0].Height = new GridLength(0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```